# averaging numpy array duplicate rows efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, duplicates

I have numpy arrays like this:

```
old=([[5.00000000e+00, 3.39622642e-03],
       [5.00000000e+00, 5.84905660e-04],
       [1.00000000e+01, 4.15094340e-04],
       [1.50000000e+01, 2.26415094e-03],
       [2.00000000e+01, 4.90566038e-02],
       [2.50000000e+01, 4.90566038e-01],
       [3.00000000e+01, 4.90566038e-01],
       [4.00000000e+01, 8.11320755e-01],
       [4.00000000e+01, 1.00000000e+00]])
```

where the first column is depth and second column is some measurements. I need to efficiently (fast as there are many of them) average measurements of duplicate rows (rows with same depth) and replace old row with new calculated average like this:

```
new=([[5.00000000e+00, 1.99056600e-03],
       [1.00000000e+01, 4.15094340e-04],
       [1.50000000e+01, 2.26415094e-03],
       [2.00000000e+01, 4.90566038e-02],
       [2.50000000e+01, 4.90566038e-01],
       [3.00000000e+01, 4.90566038e-01],
       [4.00000000e+01, 9.05660377e-01]])
```

Comment: Should your array length really change?

Comment: Not necessarily. But I don't want extra data point likes zero. I think NaN is fine as it doesn't get plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pandas` for manipulating this data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(old)
```

gives

```
    0       1
0   5.0     0.003396
1   5.0     0.000585
2   10.0    0.000415
3   15.0    0.002264
4   20.0    0.049057
5   25.0    0.490566
6   30.0    0.490566
7   40.0    0.811321
8   40.0    1.000000
```

Then just take advantage of `groupby` by grouping the first column and `aggregating` by `mean` (using `.mean()` or `.agg('mean')`. Finally, access your `.values` to get back a `np.array` with the resulting values

```
df.groupby(0).mean().reset_index().values

array([[  5.00000000e+00,   1.99056604e-03],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   4.15094340e-04],
       [  1.50000000e+01,   2.26415094e-03],
       [  2.00000000e+01,   4.90566038e-02],
       [  2.50000000e+01,   4.90566038e-01],
       [  3.00000000e+01,   4.90566038e-01],
       [  4.00000000e+01,   9.05660378e-01]])
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thx

Comment: @Bob Glad I could help :)  Please accept the answer if you think this helped

Answer (score 1):

This is admittedly not vectorized, but a pure `numpy` way with list comprehension can be obtained like this:

```
new = np.stack([np.mean(old[np.where(old[:,0] == i)], axis=0) for i in np.unique(old[:,0])])


>>> new
array([[5.00000000e+00, 1.99056604e-03],
       [1.00000000e+01, 4.15094340e-04],
       [1.50000000e+01, 2.26415094e-03],
       [2.00000000e+01, 4.90566038e-02],
       [2.50000000e+01, 4.90566038e-01],
       [3.00000000e+01, 4.90566038e-01],
       [4.00000000e+01, 9.05660378e-01]])
```

Comment: This is also working but it was OK to convert to pandas and return it back. Thx